# Add > (greater than) sign to the end of the links with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add `>` to the end of all `href`s using CSS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `:after` selector and the `content` property:

```
a:after {
    content: ">";
}
```

Note that pseudo-elements created this way are not part of the DOM and therefore you can't get a reference to them in JavaScript.

Comment: Darn, I was 20 seconds off posting! +1

Comment: If the page contains named anchors and you don't want to add the `>` to those anchors, use `a:link:after, a:visited:after` instead.

Comment: @BoltClock - Nice one, didn't think of that.

Comment: @Romario - I'm afraid not (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15)... if you want to do that you may have to resort to JavaScript.